# How to replace all empty spaces and new line from text extracted from json using beautiful soup ?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In a container of `div` with a specific class, I have some text with different id's `dd`, `dl` and `dt` having spaces and lines and some special character like `\, ?` etc. How to get rid of it ?

```
container = soup.find_all(name="div", attrs={"class":"4_square"})
```

size of container is 1. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to find all `dd` and `dt` and then replace all special characters and empty spaces by replacing it to the default value. I have mentioned below code that you may try.

```
subject = container[0]
for i in range (0,len(subject.dl.findAll('dd'))):
    temp = subject.dl.find_all('dt')[i].text.strip('\n').replace('\n','').replace(' ','').replace('\?','')
    temp1 = subject.dl.find_all('dd')[i].text.strip('\n').replace('\n','').replace(' ','').replace('\?','')
```

temp and temp1 will give you the text. I hope this works for you.

Comment: thanks for your response, this is not exactly what I want but I understood how you are doing things. If I have some numbers also that I want to remove from text, should I use .replace?

Comment: @yan yes you can use .replace to remove numbers as well but make sure numbers are of no importance to you for later usage. But as far as special characters are considered, its always advised to replace one by one and keep an eye on output.